# Is it possible to set an action to a JComponent without reseting its properties?

Tags: java, swing, events, action, awt

I've read the Java trail oracle provides and they said that the objects properties are set to match the actions properties. I would like to know if this is a limited set of properties that is shared, or if the Action is casted to the same class as the object you are setting the action to.

Another question I have is such... is it possible to set the Action to have the same properties as the Component that I'm setting it to so that it doesn't reset everything? The only work around that I can think of is either setting the action for the object before doing anything with the object, or passing the object through the actions methods or constructor and setting all the values you want at that point. I was hoping however I could set the actions at a later time in the program without disturbing anything, it be more convenient.

Example ...

```
JMenuItem myItem = new JMenuItem("someText");
myItem.setAction(myAction);// Clears the text from my menu item which is the problem
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify: what is it exactly that you're trying to do? I mean from more of a "meta" perspective as well as from a user experience point of view as you really don't mention this. And what is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Why not have "someText" associated with the Action from the get-go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me:

> Why not have "someText" associated with the Action from the get-go?

You:

> How do I do that?

Solution:

```
  // can also pass in an icon to this constructor as a 2nd parameter
  Action myAction = new AbstractAction("Some Text") {
     {
        // set properties here including mnemmonic
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
     }

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // action initiated code goes here
     }
  };
```

Also you can set the button's text via the Action's NAME property:

```
  Action myAction = new AbstractAction() {
     {
        putValue(NAME, "Some Text");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
     }

     // ... etc...
  };
```

Comment: So my only guess is that abstractaction indeed contains all the same variables and properties as my components. I would even go as so far to claim that all these components share the same properties and variables as all the other components. Am I right?

Comment: @Mr.Student: I'm not sure what properties your components may have, but it's probably far-fetched to state that the Action shares *all*. It will share the title (NAME), the MNEMONIC, any Icons that have been added. The API will tell you all the properties that are available for Actions.